# Add Event Listener to items by Class in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table component( external library ) and i want to add click event listener to table cells, so that i can copy the table cell content, this is the code i tried

```
componentDidMount(){
    
    let tableCells = document.getElementsByClassName('Table__cell');
    for (let i = 0; i < tableCells.length; i++) {
        console.log(tableCells[i]);
        tableCells[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log(i);
        }, false);
    }
}
```

i know that this is not working because the collection length is 0 even though we have the collection. what is the solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` fires long before the DOM is rendered, so the elements don't exist in the DOM.

Mixing classic DOM and React is, however, generally a nightmare and you'll get all sorts of issues as the DOM mutates.

Use event bubbling instead.

```
const handler = event => console.log(event.target.textContent);

return <div onClick={handler}><ThirdPartyTableComponent /></div>
```

If the cells contain elements you might need to make your logic a bit smarter and search up the DOM tree via `parentNode` until you find a table cell (so you get all the content in the table cell and not the content of, for example, a span inside a cell).